# Passing variables to function and lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want passing **HashMap** and element - **Foo** to my **function**. 
I don't understand variables lifetimes. Please help.

Result : error[**E0623**]: **lifetime mismatch**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

fn add_to_map<'l>(map: &'l HashMap<u32, &'l Foo>,  element : &'l Foo) 
{
    map.insert(1, element);
}

fn main()
{
    let mut map: HashMap<u32, &Foo> = HashMap::new();

    let v = 5;
    let mut f = Foo { x: &v };
    add_to_map(&map, &f);
    println!("now f is {:?}", f);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:11:19
   |
9  | fn add_to_map<'l>(map: &'l HashMap<u32, &'l Foo>,  element : &'l Foo) 
   |                                             ---                  --- these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
10 | {
11 |     map.insert(1, element);
   |                   ^^^^^^^ ...but data from `element` flows into `map` here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
9  | fn add_to_map<'l>(map: &'l HashMap<u32, &'l Foo>,  element : &'l Foo) 
   |                                             ---                  --- these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
10
```

`Foo<'a>` appears twice here (`'a` is the lifetime of `x` inside `Foo`). Since you didn't give explicit values for the lifetime `'a`, the compiler will assume that the `Foo` as the `HashMap` value and `element` `Foo` will have different lifetimes `'a`. This approach works well in general.

However, you want to actually insert `element` into `map` which requires
matching lifetimes. The compiler rejects your code since the lifetimes do not
match. You need to be explicit about the lifetimes of the `x` inside `Foo`, e.g.,

```
// Verbose.
fn add_to_map<'l>(map: &'l mut HashMap<u32, &'l Foo<'l>>,  element : &'l Foo<'l>)
```

You do not *need* to give an explicit lifetime of `map` itself since the compiler can verify at the callsite that `map` lives at least as long as `element`,

```
// Slightly less verbose.
fn add_to_map<'l>(map: &mut HashMap<u32, &'l Foo<'l>>,  element : &'l Foo<'l>)
```

Note that in any case `map` needs to be `mut` in `add_to_map`.

Comment: Ok. That's works. 
But when I will print content of map then I have error. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cdc6edebc8c38be79891997e65b71cf3

Comment: The immediate issue there is that `add_to_map` borrows `map` so using it in the same scope can be unsound. I am not sure what exact problem you are trying to solve, but `add_to_map` seems weird to me; if you could e.g.,  just insert in a place like `main` you would not be running into this issue (you could delegate computation of the value to a helper). But even with that the `HashMap` you have here cannot be moved which makes it hard to use (similar code would be possible in languages like C or C++, but it would also be very easy to introduce bugs that way).

Comment: Ok. How do it? I am asking for an example. Maybe I should return a new HashMap from the function?

Comment: Just insert in place?

Comment: I don't understand. Please, look and correct my example. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cdc6edebc8c38be79891997e65b71cf3

Comment: I still don't know what the actual use case is beyond an experiment with lifetimes, but I meant this, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a232a2b76c6280e2dddb7713c0161ea.

Comment: I would like modify map (add element) and print map (in next step). I solved it like this:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3741cfcef12d41763354173e90cf8480
Question: Can it be solved in C ++ style (by passing ref)?

Comment: No, I don't think this can be solved "C++ style". Already in C++ it is not clear whether `add_to_map` stores `map` away somewhere else so one would need to keep the original `map` in place. One workaround for that in C++ are comments which are not checked by the compiler. One could also encode this in the signature by requiring `map` to be passed as a non-copyable value (e.g., `unique_pt<map>`) to signal transfer of ownership and then repopulate the source value by returning a similar value from the function. The difference with Rust is that the unsafe pass by reference is illegal.

Comment: I'd go with https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35d21d0257b4fd459f153bf5b9d7def2. As `HashMap` stores most of its data on the heap this should not be too inefficient.